# Get all occurrences of specific child node within a parent

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, something like this

```
<ORG>
    <LIST_SITES>
        <SITE>
            <LIST_SERVICES>
                <SERVICE>
                    <NAME>
                    </NAME>
                    <LOCATION>
                    </LOCATION>
                </SERVICE>
                <SERVICE>
                    <NAME>
                    </NAME>
                    <LOCATION>
                    </LOCATION>
                </SERVICE>
            </LIST_SERVICES>
        </SITE>
        <SITE>
           ....
        </SITE>
    </LIST_SITES>
</ORG>
```

While parsing the XML file I have to count if multiple services within the same  node have the same name.  Currently I'm checking all  nodes within the whole file, but I need to only compare nodes for services within the same  node.  Can anyone help me with this?  I tried the following, but this is what reads all nodes.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = myDoc.SelectNodes("/ORG/LIST_SITES/SITE/LIST_SERVICES/SERVICE");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string sName = xn["NAME"].InnerText;

    if (currentNode.Value == sName)        
       //increment counter
}
```

basically I believe I have the rest of the code accurate, I just can't figure out how to load the xnList with only  nodes from the  node I'm currently looking at

Comment: so, your trouble is in only looking at SERVICE's in the LIST_SERVICE you're currently in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your document as an `XDocument` you can use the following query to find all of the nodes that share a name within the same `LIST_SERVICES` parent:

```
var query = mydoc.Descendants("LIST_SERVICES")
    .SelectMany(services => services.Elements("SERVICE")
        .GroupBy(service => service.Element("NAME").Value)
        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var serviceNodes = doc.Descendants("service");

Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach(string name in serviceNodes.Element("Name"))
{
     if(dict.ContainsKey(name))
     {
        dict[name]++;
     }
     else
     {
        dict[name]=1;
     }
}

foreach(int item in dict)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",item.Key,item.Value);
}
```